# How do you modify the IP header of a packet on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, sockets, networking

I want to set a custom TTL for an outbound IP packet in my iOS app. I know it's possible because this app [App store link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ping-analyzer-graphical-network/id406772587?mt=8) has a setting for modifying the TTL of a ping packet.

Any ideas on how this is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using sockets, then use `setsockopt()`

http://www.scottklement.com/rpg/socktut/setsockoptpapi.html